# How do i handle image comparison on CI?

Tags: protractor

We are using Protractor Image Comparison with Protractor to test some of our UI pages. We noticed that there seems to be a difference in screen shots generated on Mac/PC or CI.

Doesnt anyone have a good way to handle this (at least on Mac vs CI).

For CI we are using travisci , and to handle it what we did was all make a travis VM https://github.com/erdc/proteus/wiki/Replicating-the-TravisCI-Environment-on-your-Local-Machine then clone the branches here and generate the baselines on this VM.

This is a bit unwieldy. Does anyone do this another way? Preferable if the images can be generated on the Mac and still have them work on the CI? Or maybe a better / documented workflow for maintaining the baselines?

Comment: hi Tim Did you get it resolved? If so, how did you do that.

Comment: Hi Dinesh, we didn’t do anything else too much. We just use the docker image in the link still. Once you get used to it it’s not too bad as I thought at the time of this question. Just need to do some initial setup and then hop in and out of the VM. We documented it here in our repo https://github.com/infor-design/enterprise/blob/master/docs/TESTING.md#working-with-visual-regression-tests

Comment: Thanks Tim. Seems I need to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Run tests on CI even from local machine. In that way you will have stable understanding what is going on with your UI. 
The desire to run locally is the first thing about what you are thinking in your situation but when you test UI changes and you need always compare with Baseline and of course you have a CI... will be better to use CI always.